# how to change one button based on value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to change my ajax button based on if else condition. Like if status is 1 then it will show just active button otherwise it just show the inactive button. I have two buttons. I cant find the logic where I actually put my if else condition. My code is:

```
function showAllArticle(status = "") {

  //alert(status);
  $.ajax({
    //cache: false,
    //headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      status: status
    },
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Article/showAllUser',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    //cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

      var html = '';
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //(data[i].status);


        html += '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].id + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data[i].email + '</td>' +
          '<td>' +
          // '{% if data[i].status == 1 %}'
          '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-active" data="' + data[i].id + '">Active</a>' +
          //@if(data[i].status == 1)

          //'{% else %}' 
          '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-inactive" data="' + data[i].id + '">Inactive</a>' +
          //'{% endif %}' 
          /* '</td>' +
                   '<td>'+
                   '+@if(data[i].status == 1)+'
                   'tseting'+
                           '+@elseif(data[i].status == 0)+'
                           'debug'+

                           '+@endif+'


                   '</td>'+*/
          '</tr>';
      }
      $('#showdata').html(html);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Could not get Data from Database');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Based on the code comments, it looks like you know exactly where to put the condition.  You just need to do it with Javascript instead of whatever templating language that appears to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must apply the if condition based on JS, not on the template language you are using as JS is executed on the user end.

You must do something similar do this:

```
    html += '<tr>';
    html +=  '<td>' + data[i].id + '</td>';
    html +=  '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td>';
    html +=  '<td>' + data[i].email + '</td>';
    html +=  '<td>';
    if (data[i].status == 1) {
      html += '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-active" data="' + data[i].id + '">Active</a>';
    } else if(data[i].status == 12) {
      //...
    } else { 
      html += '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-inactive" data="' + data[i].id + '">Inactive</a>' +
    } 
      /* '</td>' +
               '<td>'+
               '+@if(data[i].status == 1)+'
               'tseting'+
                       '+@elseif(data[i].status == 0)+'
                       'debug'+

                       '+@endif+'


               '</td>'+*/
     html += '</tr>';
```